# Arguments order in controller method

Tags: php, laravel, function, arguments

Suppose we have the following route in Laravel:

```
Route::get('/blog/{id}/{slug}', ['as' => 'blog', 'uses' => 'Front\PostController@single']);
```

Where the <kbd>{id}</kbd> and the <kbd>{slug}</kbd> are variables and will be passed as arguments to **single()** method of **PostController** class as below:

```
public function single($id, $slug) {}
```

But you can also pass the **Request** object as well, like so:

```
public function single(Request $request, $id, $slug) {}
```

or even:

```
public function single($id, $slug, Request $request) {}
```

and the Laravel still can handle them fine... looks like the order of arguments does not metter or there is some special technique applied?

Comment: Laravel does some magic to make this work.

Comment: @ryantxr looks like it.. but how they achieved it?

Comment: Laravel uses reflection to look at the functions you define. Go look at the source code.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the arguments is not important except if you use a default value in those arguments (available since PHP 5.6+), like this:

```php
function something($foo, $bar=true) { ... }
```

Which should be the last ones in the arguments.

Please check the official PHP docs about ["use of default parameters in functions"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default):

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.
>
> Note that when using default arguments, **any defaults should be on the right side of any non-default arguments**; otherwise, things will not work as expected.

Comment: The default values are just values that arguments initially has, but they didn't tell anything about order and can't control the order

Comment: At `Example #4 Using non-scalar types as default values` says: "Note that when using default arguments, any defaults should be on the right side of any non-default arguments; otherwise, things will not work as expected."

Answer (score 0):

When you use:

public function single($id, $slug, Request $request) {}

You are specifying the type of $request as of Request class. So there is no special technique that laravel is using but it is just PHP philosophy that when you specify type, it maintains the order itself.

But yes, there is definitely some logic that laravel uses to use all request data in $request object.

Comment: ok, but in some point of execution, the Laravel calls your controller's action and passes the route parameter into it (in order as they specified in route... there might be variable number of parameters) and then it should pass(inject) the **$request** object also, so it become available in your action... 
but how it knows in which position it should inject the $request object (as first argument or as last argument?), because the developers are free do define their actions as they like...